# Yii2 activeRecord multiple sums from multiple join tables

Tags: mysql, activerecord, yii2

Is it possible, with ActiveRecord query builder to do multiple sums when I am joining multiple tables?

The query looks like this:

```
        $po = PurchaseOrder::find() //TODO groupby with multiple sums possible?
            ->select([
                'po.*',
                'sum(pi.invoice_units) as invoicedUnits',
                'sum(ar.received_units) as receivedArticles'
            ])
            ->from('purchase_order po')
            ->joinWith('invoice')
            ->joinWith('articlesReceived')
            ->where(['po.id' => 3960])
            ->groupBy(['po.id'])
            ->one();
```

The result that i am expeting is :

```
sum(pi.invoice_units) = 234 + 2 = 236;
sum(ar.received_units) = 10 + 6 = 16;
```

However I get this: `236*2 = 472; 16*2 = 32;`

Is it possible to do multiple sums this way? In normal sql, you would do join and then a sum inside the join, but how to do it in activeRecord?

This is the correct query that returns the right sums:

```
SELECT po.*, ars.receivedArticles, pis.invoicedUnits FROM purchase_order po
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT ar.purchase_order_id, SUM(ar.received_units) as receivedArticles FROM purchase_articles_received ar GROUP BY ar.purchase_order_id) ars ON po.id = ars.purchase_order_id
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT pi.order_id, SUM(pi.invoice_units) as invoicedUnits FROM purchase_invoice pi GROUP BY pi.order_id) pis ON po.id = pis.order_id
    WHERE po.id = 3960 GROUP BY po.id;
```

Comment: Could you add the sql query you would use to get the expected result?

Comment: @topher I added the query in the question!

Comment: Use `activeQuery` instead.